# Extremely Slow SSIS Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

Just as I thought I was getting good with SSIS.

Within an SSIS package, I am trying to use my version of Pinal Dave's XML Plan Cache Query found here: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/03/17/sql-server-practical-sql-server-xml-part-one-query-plan-cache-and-cost-of-operations-in-the-cache/

My version just adds a SELECT TOP 50 with an ORDER BY estimatedcost DESC.

My query:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT  N'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan'),
CachedPlans
(
ParentOperationID,
OperationID,
PhysicalOperator,
LogicalOperator,
EstimatedCost,
EstimatedIO,
EstimatedCPU,
EstimatedRows,
PlanHandle, 
QueryText,
QueryPlan,
CacheObjectType,
ObjectType)
AS
(
SELECT
RelOp.op.value(N'../../@NodeId', N'int') AS ParentOperationID,
RelOp.op.value(N'@NodeId', N'int') AS OperationID,
RelOp.op.value(N'@PhysicalOp', N'varchar(50)') AS PhysicalOperator,
RelOp.op.value(N'@LogicalOp', N'varchar(50)') AS LogicalOperator,
RelOp.op.value(N'@EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost ', N'float') AS EstimatedCost,
RelOp.op.value(N'@EstimateIO', N'float') AS EstimatedIO,
RelOp.op.value(N'@EstimateCPU', N'float') AS EstimatedCPU,
RelOp.op.value(N'@EstimateRows', N'float') AS EstimatedRows,
cp.plan_handle AS PlanHandle,
st.TEXT AS QueryText,
qp.query_plan AS QueryPlan,
cp.cacheobjtype AS CacheObjectType,
cp.objtype AS ObjectType
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans cp
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(cp.plan_handle) st
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(cp.plan_handle) qp
CROSS APPLY qp.query_plan.nodes(N'//RelOp') RelOp (op)
)
SELECT TOP 50
PlanHandle,
ParentOperationID,
OperationID,
PhysicalOperator,
LogicalOperator,
QueryText,
CacheObjectType,
ObjectType,
EstimatedCost,
EstimatedIO,
EstimatedCPU,
EstimatedRows
FROM CachedPlans
WHERE CacheObjectType = N'Compiled Plan'
ORDER by estimatedcost desc;
```

In SSMS this query runs in the sub 30 second range but when I execute it in the SSIS package it takes 3-4 hours to complete, if it completes at all before maintenance trumps it.

The SSIS package executes at night when the server has very little load and then exports the results to a CSV text file.

The package seems to do fine until it gets to the execution of the query and then it just hangs, for hours.

Server Stats:
Server 2008 (64 bit)
SQL Server 2008R2 (64 bit)
24 GB RAM (16 to SQL, 8 to OS)
E5620 @2.4 GHz (2 procs)

Edit:
Things that I have tried:

--Writing the output to a global temp table (and a regular table) and then querying that table for the output.
--Within the SSIS package, creating and then executing a stored procedure with the query that outputs to a temp table (and a regular table) and then querying that table for the output.

Comment: It's possible the SSIS package does not have enough memory to assign buffers so it has to accept the data very slowly from the table. I suggest you load the data to a trash destination, and this will rule out the CSV target as the issue

Comment: Also, when you run this in SSMS, do you wait for all 50 records to arrive?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid: I have attempted to speed things up by writing the output to both global temp tables and regular tables without any discernible change to the speed. Yes, I am waiting on all 50 records to arrive. I'll update my post with this info as well.

Comment: If the SSMS version is fast and the SSIS one is slow I suggest you solve that problem rather than complicating it with temp tables etc. This link http://picnicerror.net/development/sql-server/optimising-ssis-read-from-view-ole-db-source-2013-12-19/ suggests changing your SSIS package source from "Table or View" to "SQL Command". It would really help if you gave more details about the SSIS aspect as I don't know what you currently have it set to

Comment: Why you using `CROSS APPLY` ? I think your first query generate a lot records by multiplying lines of each table....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are very sure that query is not taking time .

1) create  SP

```
 a) if exit drop the table  (Think a unique name)

 b) create TABLE (SAME unique name)

 c) INSERT the result into the table
```

2   create SSIS Package

```
  a) Call the sp in execute sql task

  b) Create data flow select all data from the table (created in sp) and dump in cSV using flat file destination .
```

or

As per your question Query executes very fast in ssms , and you are doing any transformation on result set in ssis.

Try BCP output command

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms162802.aspx

Comment: I have tried the things that you have suggested and I did not see a gain in speed. I have updated my original post to include your suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: As per your  question Query executes very fast in ssms .and you are doing any Transformation  on result set ,Try BCP output command https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms162802.aspx

Comment: It looks like I was over complicating things. Your BCP idea is brilliant in it's simplicity. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As another way, you can create multiple temp tables and process each join and dump the data into the table .. finally last temp table holding the whole dataset
  You can do this task using the SSIS sql task

Comment: As you suggest, I will try breaking everything out into separate tables and then combining. I'll update as soon as I can get this rewritten and tried out. Thanks!